# How to tell the difference between Heroku Config Variables vs .Env Variables

Tags: node.js, heroku, key

I'm a native iOS Swift dev and I have lightly dabbled in `Node.js` so this process is a little foreign to me.

Using node if I want to hide my variables I first import the `dotenv module`, `require` it in my `app.js` file, set `.env` variables, add it to a `.gitignore` file, and then use the `dotenv` module to access them:

```
// on the cli
$ npm install dotenv --save
$ touch .env
$ touch .gitignore 

// in the .env file
MY_SECRET_KEY=12345
// finally add the .env file to the .gitignore filel

// in the app.js file
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

initializeSomethingWith(process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY)
```

In Heroku I set the keys as secret using:

```
$ heroku config:set MY_SECRET_KEY=123456789
$ git push heroku master
```

I access the heroku config variable using:

```
process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY
```

Where my confusion lies is once I require the `dotenv module`, how can it tell the difference between whatever is inside the .env file vs whatever I set for the heroku variables?

app.js file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

var isThisAHerokuKey = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY // key is 123456789

var orIsThisADotEnvKey = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY // key is 12345

initializeSomethingWith(process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY) // which key is this using?
```

Of course common sense would say just don't name the keys the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while it seems that if I run the file locally by running `npm start` it will use the value of 12345 but if it’s used remotely on Heroku then it will use the value of 123456789.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

// REMOTE VALUE
var isThisAHerokuKey = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY // key is 123456789

// LOCAL VALUE
var orIsThisADotEnvKey = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY // key is 12345

// DEPENDS ON WETHER USED LOCALLY or REMOTELY
initializeSomethingWith(process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY)
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to work with environment variables in node.js on Heroku is NOT to explicitly `require('dotenv')` in your code.
Instead, set your env vars for your Heroku apps with `heroku config:set` as you have been doing.
In your development environment, put your local env vars in your `.env` file, but DON'T add .env to git (i.e. put it in your `.gitignore`).
Then, use `heroku local` to run your app (based on your `Procfile`).
When `heroku local` executes your app, it takes your env vars defined in .env, so that they can be referenced in your code via `process.env.ENV_VAR_XYZ`.

See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) for more details.

Comment: If you're running/debugging an app locally, or via an IDE, I'm assuming you wouldn't be using `heroku local`